# C# MVC - Routing Issue / Confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am developing one application in the `ASP.NET` `MVC` `C#` on the `.NET 4` framework.

I confused in `routing` and I do the research and developed the one demo version It works as I want but I want to know is which method is best practice for developing application.

First I register the route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "RoutesTesting",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Test", e = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

I have one class that have the properties and it's name same as the route's parameter.

```
class MyClass{
    public string a{get;set;}
    public string b{get;set;}
    public string c{get;set;}
    public string d{get;set;}
    public string e{get;set;}
}
```

Now I created the tow methods that works find and get the data from the URL successfully.

Method 1:

```
public ActionResult Test(MyClass objMyClass){

}
```

Method 2:

```
public ActionResult Test(string a,string b,string c,string d,string e=String.Empty){

}
```

My question is:

1. Is routing doing that conversation in my action method? Like it convert the parameter values in the `MyClass' object's properties?
2. Which method is best practice to use?
3. Is method 1 will throw any error or exception when the conversation is not possible ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I guess i've never seen a good url with that many `/` so Method 2 is what I would normally use for a route, I would only use Method 1 for a POST of a model back to the server.

Comment: Okay Thank you @AshleyMedway. So the Method 2 is good to use.

Comment: Well if both work you can use whatever you want...

Comment: Yeah, Both is working but I want to know which one is better to use ?

Comment: Whatever you want, StackOverflow is not the place for which is better. You can use either just fine. It depends on your project. Keep the same convention in your project.

Comment: Your question is off-topic on Stack Overflow, Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Thank you @AshleyMedway. I will go with the `Method 2` for safe and secure to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is a part of ASP.NET's Model Binding. It's the magic that lets you send across a JSON object of `{"firstName":"Jonathon","lastName":"Chase"}` and have to automagically be mapped to a model Person that looks like so:

```
public class Person {
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

The fact that you can create a route like that is merely a consequence of this. Model Binding is a complex subject, but I can touch on some aspects of how you're forming your route, especially if the action you're creating is going to have a side-effect, such as writing to a database.

Typically if you're going to have a method that will effect state, you should use an Http verb other than Get, and send the model across in the body of the request, rather than in the query/url string. The Model Binding will take care of the mapping for you either way.

You should prefer to use a strong model rather than multiple primitives as parameters, especially in cases where the information will be sent in the body of a request over the query string.

These points are debatable, however, and shouldn't be considered hard or fast rules for the most part.

As to your last point, if the parameters are incorrect enough that the Route can't identifier the action or controller, you should get a 404. However, if you have a valuetype that isn't nullable as an expected routed property that isn't properly sent across, you should expect a 500 with an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: I have use that `Query Parameter` to get records from the `Databases` and also I `Passed` that `Query Parameter` to my view to display on the screen.

Comment: Thanks Man, Now I will go with the `Method 2` as your `answer` said that it is more safe to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How model binding works](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/model-binding.html#how-model-binding-works)

> Is routing doing that conversation in my action method? Like it
>   convert the parameter values in the `MyClass' object's properties?

The framework model binder is doing the conversion based on the actions parameter.

> Which method is best practice to use?

That is an opinionated question. Depends on which one suits your needs. The framework handles both.

> Is method 1 will throw any error or exception when the conversation is
>   not possible ?

Model binder will pass null to the action parameter for the properties that don't match.

Comment: Thanks, But if the `Parameter` value does not able to `Convert` in to the `matched` properties types? so what happen ?

Comment: @JonathonChase explained that last point better in his answer.